# Are two calls to nextval() for the same sequence deterministic within one query?

Tags: postgresql

With Postgres (13), given that I have:

1. A sequence called `example_sequence`
2. A table called `example_table` with just two `bigint` fields, called `val1` and `val2`

Now, I add a row to the table, like so:

```
insert into example_table (val1, val2) 
values (
    nextval('example_sequence'::regclass), 
    nextval('example_sequence'::regclass)
);
```

**The question**: For this new row, is `val2` always guarenteed to be `val1 + 1`?

Or is it possible that some other call to `nextval` for that sequence (e.g., in another session) will occur between the two calls above, and therefore increment the sequence, so that `val2` is greater than `val1 + 1`?

Comment: From the manual: To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, the value obtained by nextval is not reclaimed for re-use if the calling transaction later aborts.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I don't think that statement is related to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For this new row, is val2 always guarenteed to be val1 + 1?

No, it's not.

There could be a concurrent transaction that also calls `nextval('example_sequence')` exactly *between* the two calls from your statement.

In general, you should never rely on sequence generated values to be gapless. The only thing you can rely on is that they are incrementing and unique.